# How to open a browser on click of Submit button

Tags: javascript, jsp, struts, struts-1

In my application, on click of a Submit button (Struts), an action class method gets executed which sets the "Updated URL" property of the bean. What I want is I need the URL opened in a new browser after the setting bean is done without the user having to do anything else like clicking the link. I'm not able to find the right way of doing this.

Here is some code:

my JSP:

```
<html:submit property="evaluation">
  <c:choose>
    <c:when test="Some Condition"><fmt:message key="Button1" /></c:when>
    <c:otherwise><fmt:message key="Button2" /></c:otherwise>
  </c:choose>
</html:submit>
```

Comment: Why dont you do with javascript using window.open

Comment: Hi Shadow.. I read that a javascript method can't be called on click of a "Submit" button. Or can it be? Where do I use window.open?

Comment: Nope it can be called, and its easier to open new browser window

Answer (score 0):

On click of the submit button, invoke the action via AJAX and let the action send back json data with the URL you want to navigate to. in the AJAX handler, use the url returned in the json data and open it in a new window